# There is an error when it comes to cvReleaseImage from openCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to get numbers from Image commonly called OCR.

But when i used `cvMatchTemplate()`, there is an error (vshost32.exe operation is stopped.)

It takes my time for about 2 hours to find reason. Fortunately, I figured out that this error comes from `cvReleaseImage()`.

Since my English level is somewhat low, i can't understand question related to this matter on the Internet.

So I need your help. Thank you.

Below is my code. I used OpenCV similar to C++ dll.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int opencv_UV()
{
double min, max;
double _max;
int index[4];
CvPoint left_top;
IplImage *B[10];
IplImage *C;
B[0]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\0.bmp", -1);
B[1]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\1.bmp", -1);
B[2]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\2.bmp", -1);
B[3]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\3.bmp", -1);
B[4]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\4.bmp", -1);
B[5]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\5.bmp", -1);
B[6]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\6.bmp", -1);
B[7]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\7.bmp", -1);
B[8]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\8.bmp", -1);
B[9]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\9.bmp", -1);



for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{       
    char name[20];
    strcpy(name,"../Debug");
    char a[1];
    itoa(i,a,1);
    strcat(name, a);
    strcat(name, ".bmp");       
    IplImage *A = cvLoadImage(name, -1);        

    for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        C = cvCreateImage( cvSize( A->width - B[j]->width+1, A->height - B[j]->height+1 ), IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1 );
        cvMatchTemplate(A, B[j], C, CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
        cvMinMaxLoc(C, &min, &max, NULL, &left_top);

        if(_max<max)
        {
            _max=max;
            index[i]=j;
        }

        cvReleaseImage(&C);     // I checked there was no error until this point.
    }
    cvReleaseImage(&A);

}

for(int k=0; k<10; k++)
{
    cvReleaseImageHeader(&B[k]);
}

int result=index[0]*1000 + index[1]*100 + index[2]*10 + index[3];

return result;
}
```

Comment: It sounds that the `C#` tag is irrelevant to this question...

Comment: How is c# relevant here?

Comment: I use this method like dll in c#

Comment: @AaronSeo: You better to remove the tag...

Comment: Okay sorry. I thought this error is possible to occured because i use it in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image **header** and image **data** are different things.

[`cvCreateImage()` is equivalent to](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#createimage) executing:

```
header = cvCreateImageHeader(size, depth, channels);
cvCreateData(header);
```

and [`cvReleaseImage()` can be seen as](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#releaseimage) a shortcut to:

```
if(*image )
{
    cvReleaseData(*image);
    cvReleaseImageHeader(image);
}
```

With that in mind, the following functions work in pairs:

- `cvLoadImage()` brother is `cvReleaseImage()`;
- `cvCreateImage()` brother is also `cvReleaseImage()`;
- But only `cvCreateImageHeader()` is brother to `cvReleaseImageHeader()`;

Adjust your code to respect these rules.

**One more thing**: `cvLoadImage()` can fail! This means that is a good idea to **code defensively and test the return of this function**:

```
B[0]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\0.bmp", -1);
if (B[0] == NULL) {
    // Most probably, the file doesn't exist. Deal with error and
    return;
}

B[1]=cvLoadImage("Reference_UV\\1.bmp", -1);
if (B[1] == NULL) {
    // Most probably, the file doesn't exist. Deal with error and
    return;
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted as an answer,since i can't add a comment(reputation problem). You have to release the header first and then free the image data. If you do it the other way, i.e., free image data and then call cvReleaseImageHeader() function, then it deceptively works. But internally it leaks memory and after sometime your application will crash. You can also debug step by step to see the values of IplImage* C, to see if it's null, this is prob the reason why it's crashing.